# create record on joins table from two other tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a `Recipe` model and an `Ingredient` model. They both `has_many :recipe_ingredients` and Recipe `has_many :ingredients, through: recipe_ingredients` and Ingredient `has_many :recipes, through: recipe_ingredients` and RecipeIngredient `belongs_to` both Recipe and Ingredient. Coming from the `recipe#show` I have a `link_to` `new_recipe_ingredient_path(@recipe)`. In that view I have

```
<%= form_for @recipe_ingredient do |f| %>
    <%= f.collection_select :ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name %>

    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <%= f.number_field :amount %>
    <%+ f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My question is, what do I need in my `ingredients_controller` to create the record in `RecipeIngredient` table? I have tried shoveling in the params. I have tried straight up creating the RecipeIngredient in the INgredient controller and get a forbidden attributes error. I try other things and get a typemismatch. I'm wondering if I can redirect to the create method in the REcipeINgredient controller and create it there.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I tried both of those and didn't work. My new `form-for` looks very similar except I have

```
<%= form_for [@recipe_ingredient] do |f|%>
    <%= f.collection_select :ingredient_id, Ingredient.all, :id, :name %>

    <%= f.label :amount %>
    <%= f.number_field :amount, step: :any %>

    <%= f.submit 'Add Ingredient' %>
<% end %>
```

And in my Ingredients Controller

```
def new
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
  @ingredient = Ingredient.new
  @recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.new
end

def create
  @recipe = Recipe.find(params[:recipe_id])
  @ingredient = Ingredient.find(params[:recipe_ingredient][:ingredient_id])
  @recipe_ingredient = RecipeIngredient.create(
    recipe: @recipe,
    ingredient: @ingredient,
    amount: params[:recipe_ingredient][:amount]
  )

  redirect_to recipe_path(@recipe)
end
```

I know it's not the prettiest but it works, :P

Comment: its better to prefer the `save` version over `create` while creating a record and redirecting to some path as it will allow you to make some validation check. e.g. `if @recipe_ingredient.save; redirect_to ...; end`

Comment: Ya, this was just to go from red to green :D Thank you so much for taking the time to help :D

Comment: you have figured your solution out yourself...kudos! :)

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question "what do I need in my ingredients_controller to create the record in RecipeIngredient table?" Your code is trying to create Ingredients from recipes which is the opposite, but I'll assume that you are trying to achieve your question, so here is:

Modify or add this at your controller

```
class IngredientsController < ApplicationController
 def ingredient_params
 params.require(:ingredient).permit(
   :id,
   :your_attributes_here,
   {:recipe_ids => []}
 end
end
```

at your view :

```
<%= form_for @ingredient do |f| %>
 <%= f.collection_select :recipe_ids, Recipe.all, :id, :name, {}, { multiple: true } %>
<% end %>
```